# Where is Oracle Fusion Assets REST APIs?

Tags: oracle-apps, oracle-fusion-apps

From my understanding, Oracle Fusion apps on the cloud and Oracle Cloud SaaS Services are interchangeable. I was trying to locate the [Oracle Fusion Assets](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/financials/19b/faalm/toc.htm) REST APIs which should be under [Oracle Financials Cloud APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/financials/19b/farfa/index.html) but I wasn't able to.

Can someone point me to the right direction on locating the REST APIs for Oracle Fusion Assets?

Thanks

Comment: is this what you are looking for? https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/service/19c/cxsvc/api-assets.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

**List of Financial APIs:**
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/financials/18c/farfa/rest-endpoints.html

**List of Common APIs:**
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/applications-common/19b/farca/rest-endpoints.html

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Fusion Cloud has provided all rest API in One location at One Location.
But there are different versions of Oracle Fusion Cloud.

And every quarter we get new patch bundle. The current version is 19B as of August 2019. But it may vary on the customer to customer depending on when they subscribe to the patch bundle.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/applications-common/19b/farca/rest-endpoints.html

Please refer above link and let us know if you have any questions.

Thanks,
Raghu

Comment: Thank you Raghu, I'm sorry for the late reply. I wasn't able to find the fixed assets related APIs in any version of Oracle Fusion Cloud. There is just no API to insert/update fixed assets into Oracle Fusion Cloud?